# Grade averaging in assembly language crashes

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

I am trying to adapt some code we developed in class and am having a problem.

Here is the code we developed in class -- take 10 numbers, average them.

```
    include irvine32.inc
    Title GetTen
    .data
    inprompt db "Enter a number:",0
    sumMsg db "The sum of your numbers is ",0
    avgMsg db "The average of your number is ",0
    nums    db 10 dup(0) ;duplicate nums 10 times for indirect 
    sum db 0
    divisor db 0
   .code

    main proc 

    call getValues
    call sumValues
    call calcAvg

    exit
    jmp ENDITALL
    ;SUM 10 VALUES
    sumValues proc
    mov ebx,offset nums
    mov ecx, lengthof nums
    sub eax,eax
    SumLoop:
    add al,[ebx]
    add ebx,1
    loop SumLoop
    mov sum,al
    mov edx,offset sumMsg
    call WriteString
    call WriteInt

    call crlf
    ret
    sumValues endp

    ;READ 10 Numbers in proc 
    getValues PROC
    mov ebx, offset nums
    mov ecx, lengthof nums
    InLoop:
    mov edx, offset inprompt
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    call crlf
    mov [ebx],al
    add ebx,1 ;add one to advance the nums array 
    loop InLoop
    ret
    getValues endp

    ;--------Calculate the average
    calcAvg proc
    mov ebx, lengthof nums
    mov divisor,bl
    call dumpregs
    div bl ;the first operand is always eax 
   ;call dumpregs
    mov edx, offset avgMsg
    call writestring
    movsx eax,al
   ;call dumpregs
    call writeInt
    ret
    calcAvg endp


    ENDITALL:

    main endp
    end main
```

That code runs great.  I need to adapt that into a grade calculator (put in ten numeric grades, average them, then compare the average to some pre-canned values to assign a numeric grade.)   All basic stuff, except AL doesn't like numbers like 100 too much -- if I enter, say, 5 100's and 5 80's it tells me the sum of the numbers is 132 and the average is 13.

OK, so I tried both AH and EAX in place of AL, figuring that there wasn't enough room in AL.  Here is that code.

```
    include irvine32.inc
    Title GradeAverage
    .data
    inprompt db "Enter a grade:",0
    sumMsg db "The sum of your numbers is ",0
    avgMsg db "The average of your grade is ",0
    nums    dd 10 dup(0) ;duplicate nums 10 times for indirect 
    sum dd 0
    divisor dd 0
   .code

   main proc 

  call getValues
  call sumValues
  call calcAvg

  exit
  jmp ENDITALL
  ;SUM 10 VALUES
  sumValues proc
  mov ebx,offset nums
  mov ecx, lengthof nums
  sub eax,eax
  SumLoop:
  add eax,[ebx]
  add ebx,1
  loop SumLoop
  ;mov sum,eax ;I shouldn't even need this anymore since we're using all the       same size.
  mov edx,offset sumMsg
  call WriteString
  call WriteInt

  call crlf
  ret
  sumValues endp

  ;READ 10 Numbers in proc 
  getValues PROC
  mov ebx, offset nums
  mov ecx, lengthof nums
  InLoop:
  mov edx, offset inprompt
  call WriteString
  call ReadInt
  call crlf
  mov [ebx],eax
  add ebx,1 ;add one to advance the nums array 
  loop InLoop
  ret
  getValues endp

  ;--------Calculate the average
  calcAvg proc
  mov esi, lengthof nums
  mov divisor,esi
  call dumpregs
  div esi ;the first operand is always eax 
 ;call dumpregs
  mov edx, offset avgMsg
  call writestring
  ;movsx eax,eax
  ;call dumpregs
  call writeInt
  ret
  calcAvg endp


  ENDITALL:

  main endp
  end main
```

This code crashes.  It will take the numbers, and if I put, say 100 5 times and 50 5 times, it tells me the sum is -42041476 and then crashes.

It's probably something really basic, but I'm at a loss.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The usual thing ... forgetting that `div esi` will use `edx` as the top 32 bits of the dividend. Although that doesn't affect the summing. `add ebx,1` is wrong too, you need `add ebx,4` since each integer is 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least one bug and some conceptual issues.

Concept: EAX is the name of a 32 bit register; the lower 16 bits of that register are called AX. In AX the lower 8 bits are called AL and the higher - AH.

Concept: an N-bit instruction that involves memory reads/writes N bits in memory. When you use AL you'd read/write 8 bits, and when you use EAX you'd read/write 32 bits.

.... so your main sum loop has a bug, it reads 32 bits from memory every time:

```
 SumLoop:
  add eax,[ebx]
  add ebx,1
  loop SumLoop
```

Lets say you have bytes [1,2,3,4] at [EBX]. First loop will add 1234H to EAX, subsequent loops are unknown because the memory you're reading is out of the bounds of your array. The crash may be due to this or something entirely different.

If your data are bytes you can read them one-by-one:

```
  xor edx, edx
SumLoop:
  mov dl,[ebx]
  add eax, edx
  inc ebx
  loop SumLoop
```

And in your average proc you have `div esi` but before you div your EDX must be zeroed because you're dividing [EDX,EAX] 64-bit number to ESI. You need to add `xor dx,dx` before that instruction